# Showing the setup screen only on first launch in kivy

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, python-3.8, kivymd

I am trying to make an app with kivy and kivymd but I can't figure out how I can make the setup screen show up only the first time. This is how the application is going to work: User launches the application after installation and is being shown the sign up/log in screen, And once the user is done with the setup, the setup screens will never appear again unless the user reinstalls the application.

How can I make this happen?
Please help and thanks SO much in advance!

Comment: What setup screen?

Comment: If your setup screen accomplishes something, then you just check if that thing has been accomplished and decide which screen to show based on tat determination.

Comment: @JohnAnderson I'm trying to use SignUp / LogIn screens only the first time that the user launches the application.Once the user is done with signing up / logging in those screens should never appear again unless the user reinstalls the application.I am about to use a boolean object to check if those screens have been shown or not,but I don't think this is the correct way.

Comment: Does your `SignUp` save any information in a file or database?

Comment: @JohnAnderson  yes.It sends the user information to the database.

Comment: Then check for that information in the database and decide which screen to show based on that.

Comment: @JohnAnderson.Thank you so much.But I think there should be another way to do this without checking the database,a way to check the system or something like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this problem by creating and reading a "text" file.My "text" file has '0' as a `boolean` variable .Once the user is done with signing up / logging in , I change that "text" file to '1' ,and in the `__init__` func, I check if that file equals to '0' or '1'.
I'm not sure if this is the correct way or not,but this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

It is so easy just follow this:
**First import os module and then use a conditional statement**

Note: Here I have two screens, 'start' and 'intro' , I want to show my 'intro' screen if it's the first time the user start the app, and for next times he/she won't face this screen ever. If user started this app before there will be 'database.db' file and app should start with 'start' screen, otherwise app should be started with 'intro' screen which for me contains an function.

Code will be something like the following:

```
from os.path import exists

def on_enter(self,*args):

    if exists('database.db'):
        self.ids.screenmanager.current = 'start'
    else:
        self.animIt()
```

my kvfile is like this:

```
<MyScreen>:
    MDScreenManager:
        id:screenmanager
        MDScreen:
            name:'intro'
        MDScreen:
            name:'start'
```

Depending on your app items change